# Accepting request body in controller method

Tags: spring-boot, java-8

In my controller, i have a method mapped with following mapping : 
@PostMapping("/").

This method expects a request body which i am trying to capture as mentioned below :

public String create(@RequestBody Task task)

Task is a custom class i have created which maps to the structure of request body expected in the request.

I am new to spring boot and not sure how the best practice standards are.

My doubt here is in my method create() should i directly capture the request body in my entity class or should have a similar pojo to capture the request body and then i map it to my entity class?

Any suggestions would be helpful regarding the best practices and standard conventions.

Using both the approaches it works fine for me I am just in dilemma if accepting the request body directly in entity class is a good idea and a best practice to do.

Don't want to expose my entity class in controller class as i am not sure if it is a good idea.

```
@PostMapping("/")
public String create(@Valid @RequestBody Task task) {


}
```

Task.java

```
public final class Task {

@NonNull
private int id;

@NotBlank(message = "Name is a mandatory field")
private String name;

private String decription;

@NotBlank(message = "date is a mandatory field")
private String date;

private boolean status;

@NotBlank(message = "severenes is a mandatory field")
private String severenes;

public Task(int id, String name, String decription, String date, boolean status, String severenes) {
    super();
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.decription = decription;
    this.date = date;
    this.status = status;
    this.severenes = severenes;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDecription() {
    return decription;
}

public void setDecription(String decription) {
    this.decription = decription;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public boolean isStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(boolean status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getSeverenes() {
    return severenes;
}

public void setSeverenes(String severenes) {
    this.severenes = severenes;
}
```

}

Tasks.java(Entity CLass)

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tasks")
public class Tasks {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
@Column(name = "id")
private int id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@Column(name = "date")
private LocalDateTime date;

@Column(name = "status")
private boolean status;

@Column(name = "severenes")
private String severenes;


public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}

public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}

public LocalDateTime getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(LocalDateTime date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public boolean isStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(boolean status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getSeverenes() {
    return severenes;
}

public void setSeverenes(String severenes) {
    this.severenes = severenes;
}
```

}

Both the mentioned approaches gives the same result, concern is more towards the best practices to be followed.

Answer (score 1):

It is more related to the software design principle. In this example, this is related to the Separation of Concerns. Let's imagine you are directly using a single Tasks entity for both DB operations and REST operations instead of separating it Task (kind of a DTO) and Tasks(Entity).

### Using Tasks Entity for both DB and REST Operations:

- You have a UI that shows a Tasks on a page.
- You are storing Tasks in your DB.
- Requirements are now changed. You don't store Tasks **status** in your DB anymore, instead, you need to get it dynamically from 3rd party endpoint.
- You need to remove the status field from your Tasks Entity field but you still need to return it to UI. Since you used the same entity for both layers, you can't easily and clearly remove it, what should you do, some workarounds that hard to maintain in the future?
- You need to make more work to provide this, one requirement change affected more layers that it should be.

### Using Task for REST, Tasks Entity for DB Operations

- You have a UI that shows Tasks on a page.
- You are storing Tasks in your DB.
- Requirements are now changed. You don't store Tasks **status** in your DB anymore, instead, you need to get it dynamically from 3rd party endpoint.
- You need to remove a status field from your Tasks Entity field and you can.
- You retrieved status field from 3rd party.
- You created your Task object by aggregating status from 3rd party and Tasks Entity
- You just changed one layer instead of both. UI doesn't even realize that requirements are changed, even your logical layers don't care about it. Single Responsibility Principle makes you don't fear the changes.

Yes, there may seem some drawbacks like you need more classes to represent just for a single object but it is the separation. It makes the maintainable project, easy to refactor/change the code and minimize the effects of changes.

Answer (score 0):

You should create class `CreateTaskRequest` and that class should be parameter to your controller. It is bad idea to expose your domain through endpoint. You can take a look [here](https://github.com/Calimerico/eventify/blob/master/eventify-backend/event/src/main/java/com/eventify/events/api/rest/EventController.java) how I did it on one of my projects.